# How to insert Google Ads in left and right sidebar?

Tags: php, html, css, sidebar

I want on my [site](http://rotate4refs.com/) to insert Google Ads on left and right sidebar, but I don't know how to create sidebars.

[image]

This is code from my header.php code that i have currently:

```
<?php
include "config.php";
?>
<html>
<head><meta name="adtictac-site-verification" 
content="1qvt6zbzk026xfomo6gxbxxhjk9t96obv58gpcv3n9ver69s0"><meta 
name="clckd" content="273a893ce34e0acd4ba2655313b5f902" />
 <title><?php echo $sitename; ?></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#2C60A9" leftmargin="1" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" 
marginheight="0">
<table width="777" border="2" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" 
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="border">
<tr>
<td><img src="images/header.jpg" width="777" height="210" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td background="images/bg.jpg"><table width="100%" border="0" 
cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="30%"><img src="images/links.jpg" width="231" height="17" 
alt=""></td>
    <td width="7%"><A href="index.php"><img src="images/home.jpg" width="54" 
height="17" alt="" border="0"></a></td>
    <td width="11%"><A href="join.php"><img src="images/register.jpg" 
width="83" height="17" alt="" border="0"></a></td>
    <td width="7%"><A href="faq.php"><img src="images/faq.jpg" width="54" 
height="17" alt="" border="0"></a></td>
    <td width="12%"><A href="contactus.php"><img src="images/contact-us.jpg" 
width="98" height="17" alt="" border="0"></a></td>
    <td width="12%"><A href="advertise.php"><img src="images/advertise.jpg" 
width="92" height="17" alt="" border="0"></a></td>
    <td width="21%"><A href="login.php"><img src="images/login.jpg" 
width="49" height="17" alt="" border="0"></a></td>

  </tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="bodytext">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="7%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="91%" class="bodytext"><p align="justify">

<?php
include "config.php";
$rs=mysql_query("select ID,BannerURL from bannersads where remaining>0 and 
approved=1 and adtype=1 order by rand() limit 0,1");
while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
echo "<br><center><a href=$siteurl/tr.php?id=$arr[0] target=_blank><img 
src=$arr[1] width=468 height=60 border=0></a><br></center><br>";
$rsu=mysql_query("update bannersads set remaining=remaining-1 where 
ID=$arr[0]");
}
 ?>
```

So can someone share some tips how to create sidebars where need to create placed like shown in image? I tryed inserting this:

```
<div class="google">
// Google Code here
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
.google {
margin-left:-250px;
}
```

but looks like broke my content in my homepage.

Comment: Try reading up on how to create grids in css, here's an example https://gridbyexample.com/examples/

Answer (score 1):

```
    .google {
       left: 250px;
     }
```

Also create a container and give it  width in px, not %.
Let me hope that will solve your problem.

Comment: When i add that, entire body class was moved down.. How to fix that? I inserted bellow this code:

`</tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>`

Comment: change your entire width set to % to px. i mean  `width:%;` to `width:px;`